# Puzzling use of progressive form

Tags: grammar

In this sentence:

> 僕は両親が帰ってくるまで公園で時間を**つぶしてい**なければいけなかった。
>
> I had to kill time in the park until my parents came home.

Why does 時間をつぶす need to be in the progressive form? Why can I not write ...時間をつぶさなければいけなかった。

I'm assuming 時間をつぶしている is progressive here. It certainly isn't habitual and I can't see how it would work as change of state. Thanks.

Comment: I've checked that my original sentence is as written in the book. I'm afraid you misunderstand. I have no intention of omitting いけない. I'm asking about the difference between 時間をつぶしていなければいけなかった and 時間をつぶしなければいけなかった.

Comment: Do you mean つぶ**さ**なければ by つぶ**し**なければ?

Comment: @broccoli forest Apologies. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't need to be progressive, つぶさなければ works as well.

There's not really big difference between つぶしていなければ and つぶさなければ here. I think it's parallel to "had to be killing time" and "had to kill time".